# How to drag an rect on an dragable space?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i m relativ new to web programming like javascript and d3. So maybe my basics are a bit low. Ich know to programm in Java, PHP and have a very good SQL knowlegde.

My Question is: How can I drag a rect on a dragable space. I try to program a java script where i can drag the background (in this time all objects move) and a specific object where just a one selected move.
I also try to build d3-groups because i need to work with groups in future.

I will provide my code below so maybe you can help me out.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();

var workspace_width = 500;
var workspace_height = 500;



var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", function() {
            background.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        });

var first_zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom", function() {
            first.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        });

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(Object)
  .on("drag", function(d) {
    d.x = d3.event.x;
    d.y = d3.event.y;
    draw();
  });
// Append SVG to HTML
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom)
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

//Append Background
var background = svg.append("g");

//Append to Background Stripes from up to down
background.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(d3.range(0, workspace_width, 10))
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("y2", workspace_height);

//Append to Background stripes from right to left
background.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(d3.range(0, workspace_height, 10))
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("x2", workspace_width)
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d; });

//Append Foreground to background
var foreground = background.append("g");

//Append rect to foreground
var first = foreground.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 5)
            .attr("y", 5)
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 60)
            .attr("rx", 10)
            .attr("ry", 10)
            .style("fill", "lightgray")
            .style("stroke","black")
            .style("stroke-width","2")
            .style("opacity","0.7")
            .call(first_zoom);
```

Thank you for you help
Hans

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example for dragging a rect using d3 drag behavior. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgtr9x0p/2/). Hope this helps.

```
var data = [{ x: 0, y: 0},{ x: 20, y: 20},{ x: 0, y: 60},{ x: 52, y: 0}]

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function(){
       g.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"); 
    });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height",window.innerHeight)
    .call(zoom)

var g = svg.append("g");

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d,i) { return {x:d.x, y:d.y}; })
  .on("drag", function(d) {  
      d.x = d3.event.x;
      d.y = d3.event.y;
      d3.select(this).attr("transform",function(d){ return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });       
      d3.event.sourceEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect") 
    .attr("transform",function(d){ return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; })
    .attr("width","30")
    .attr("height","40")
    .call(drag);
```

**Update** : I think, it would be better using d3 zoom behavior for panning all rectangles. Updated the fiddle URL.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not all. You wrote a solution to move one rect. I asked for a dragable object in a dragable space. For example: If you click on the background all 'rects' move like you would scroll over the space. If you click on one rect, you could change the relative position to all other rects. Thank you for reply.